# Attach external css file on Chrome Web Inspector

Tags: css, remote-debugging, web-inspector

Lets say I working with my other partner. He asked me improve his work via only CSS. But I don't have that work (web)'s files. So I can tweak some values on Browser via Web Inspector (ctrl + shift + I). I can write down all my additional styles on some note. But is there anyway create css file and attach it on live site for above purpose? So I can just send my external css file after all works done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you create a new file and store it somewhere you can access publicly like `http://localhost/style.css` and change the href value on the website to that `<link href="http://localhost/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` It will force reload the css with the new stylesheet.

I don't know if there's a cleaner/faster way to do it but it does work.

However trying something like `file:///C:/Users/[username]/Desktop/style.css` does not work as the browser will not allow you load that resource for security reasons.

Comment: I've wamp installed. So I can use localhost. But I think your solution is not really clever. Because every time I edit css file, I have to refresh page and edit html again.

Comment: @Gereltod How about using something "CSS Reloader" from the chrome store where you only have to press F9 to refresh the css?